# add class to dropdown menu inside dynamic wordpress menu

Tags: php, wordpress, dynamic

I am pretty new to wordpress and am having trouble creating the primary navigation for the site.

I am using wp-nav-menu to output my dynamic menu.

The code I would like to output is the following...

```
<ul class="mainNav">
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="">Treatments<span>&#59232;</span></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Body Treatments</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Make Up</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Skincare</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Latest News</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Aftercare</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

The code I have used to get the menu above is this...

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( 
    array( 
       'menu'       =>  'Primary Navigation',
       'items_wrap' =>  '<ul class="mainNav">%3$s</ul>'
    ) 
); ?>
```

This gets me the main menu but I do not know how to get the `<li>` with the class of dropdown. I would also like to place a `<span>` inside one of the links, as you can see in my HTML code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have figured it out and will write it here in case anyone has the same problem.

In the wordpress admin, there is a link called screen options. Open this, and tick CSS classes, you can then add individual classes to menu items.

[image: enabling css classes to nav_menu]

Comment: Lots of nice solutions as well: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%2bnav_menu%20%2bcss%20%2bclass

Comment: Its worth to note that wordpress adds this class when you indent the menu item in the order you place them in the wordpress menus. Just drag and drop it a little to the right and it will be indented a bit so it adds the `.dropdown` class. I would use your answer above if I wanted to add any other class besides `.dropdown` because wordpress already adds that by default.