# Add active class to a menu link with WordPress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am using the WordPress function **wp_nav_menu** to create my main menu.

In this menu, I have a link named "News" for exemple and I would like to make this link highlight when I am in the single.php file template.

At the moment, my code is the one below. I am not "used" to work with this WordPress function.

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu' ) ); ?>
```

Is there any way to said for exemple

```
if($is_single())
{
echo 'class="active"';
}
```

I have checked arround on SO and I founded some informations that might be interesting but nothing is really answering my question.

On this page, some one suggest to check in "Show on screen" options : [add class to dropdown menu inside dynamic wordpress menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13671669/add-class-to-dropdown-menu-inside-dynamic-wordpress-menu)

[image]

I also found this page in the codex, but I'm not sure how to use it : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#How_to_add_a_parent_class_for_menu_item

Thx in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2):

wp_nav_menu automatically add "current_page_item" class to li tag. so you can target "current_page_item" for active menu.

```
li.current_page_item a{
color:#fff;
```

`}`

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have two nice options to do that:

The first one is to add a class name to single.php main div and than add in your CSS file a property like:
`.singleClass .nav-menu ul li a {color: red; //any setting you would like }`

The other way is adding that custom class to the menu by changing `menu_class` in the call of the menu into the page.

If this is not working for you i would like to hear more about your theme hierarchy so i could be more specific with my answer.

Comment: I just figured out that I could only do <?php if(is_single()) { echo 'active' } ?>

I think it is not possible to do it as an other way?

Comment: you are correct. this is the wordpress way of doing that. you can do it in many other way but they are much more complicated and less "user friendly"

Comment: so go ahead and do so :) tell me how things worked out and if you need help i'm here

Answer (score 1):

> you can use multiple classes on nav menu like this

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu active' ) ); ?>
```

Comment: This would work perfectly if I'm on a page. But I want a page menu to be "active" while I'm on single.php or archives.php.

Answer (score 0):

In wordpress 4.x it have a class in current menu as `current_page_item` so you have to add css for class `.current_page_item` for current and active class like this

```
.current_page_item
{
border-bottom: 3px solid #50c1e9;
}
```

and see result after page refresh.